# Migration between Visual Studio Team Services projects

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

How can I migrate all source code from one Visual Studio Team Services project to another?

Comment: Please read the terms of service for this board. Questions that start "Is it possible ..." are bad questions. For one thing, it looks like you haven't done your homework and are asking this forum to solve your problem for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Tfs Integration tools](https://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/) to achieve it.

Detail steps: [Move Team Project to another Project Collection TFS 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611588/move-team-project-to-another-project-collection-tfs-2013/33633128#33633128)

> **Note:** Its a lossy data transfer.
>
> Migration - For this project, and for TFS in general, we use the term "migration" to refer to moving data between two different servers. Migration is done through the APIs of TFS, and is a lossy data
>   transfer (see the limitations listed below).
>
> Source & Limitations
>   list:https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe

Comment: I use the free TFS from Visual Studio Team Services (www.visualstudio.com), and I dont have a installation om TFS on my server. The TFS integration tool need a TFS installation. Is there a way to fix that problem?

Comment: Well, never met your situation. But this way may be the only option for you ,  a  similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681217/visual-studio-online-migration-vso-to-vso

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to migrate the code, then simply Git clone and push to another remote.
See here to do that with Git command line: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10312587/383029