# Bulk TFS Migration

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, migration, nuget, azure-devops

I have downloaded 30+ TFS projects (containing close to 100 cs projects) from my Team Services (was TFS Online).  I have modified many of those cs projects and would now like to check the changes into a different Team Services repository.  Is there an easy way to do this in bulk?

I know I can add the "files" to new Team Services repository through source control explorer, however, that appears to screw up the nuget package restore when they are downloaded.  The only way I have found that the nuget package restore works is if I open each project, disconnect it from source control, and change the source control on the open project and check it in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TFS Integration Tool](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe) to achieve Visual Studio Online migration (VSO-To-VSO)

Detail steps please see my answer in this question: [Move Team Project to another Project Collection TFS 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611588/move-team-project-to-another-project-collection-tfs-2013/33633128#33633128)  (Just need to change the TFS to VSO)

Comment: what do you mean change to "TFS to VSO"?  I'm trying to run the tool and it keeps giving me a exception "Input string was not in a correct format" attempting to convert string to int.

Comment: My mistake. I was misunderstand “my TFS Online” you mentioned. What's the detail version of your TFS? Are you using TFS on-premises  or VSTS? And which version control are you using? If you are using VSTS and want to check these projects into another VSTS repository. The best way is to remove the source control of these projects and checked in directly(For TFVC). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358951/how-can-i-completely-remove-tfs-bindings

Comment: The TFS Integration Tool is help you moving data between two different servers.(Both VSO and TFS) If you insist on this way, which step did you get "Input string was not in a correct format" this error? Could you provide a screeshot?

Comment: I think the confusion is over the product name, which changed from "TFS Online" to "Visual Studio Online (VSO)", which people now know as "Visual Studio Team Services", or "Team Services" for short.